# Using 'like' on a continuous tense

Tags: present-continuous, stative-verbs, continuous

From the movie [Misery](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0100157/):

> — You're being taken seriously.
>   — I'm delighted the critics are **liking** it.

Is the use of *like* correct in its continuous form?
I know that state verbs are not normally used on continuous tenses, but is this exception correct here?

Comment: Yes, it is. Another option would be "enjoying it."

Comment: "I'm delighted the critics like it" would almost mean the same. The difference is very slight.

Comment: @AlexK I've seen that one often used than *liking*. Is it *enjoying* more used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Americans and some British English speakers find the use of *liking* here acceptable. This is presumably due to high levels of immigration into the USA and the difficulty immigrants have learning to contrast simple and continuous tenses. This tense 'misuse' is then spread to other countries such as the UK through TV and films. There are times when the grammar 'error' can be used very effectively to add a dimension of meaning.

However, if you take an American exam such as TOEFL such uses will be marked incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, **liking** is used correctly and goes beyond just being synonymous with **approving** or **accepting** for which

> I'm delighted the critics **like** it

would suffice.  Using **liking** indicates the critics not only like it but **enjoy** it (per @AlexK) and find **multiple aspects appealing**.